# Want to send new values to object wehenver dropdwon value is selecetd

Tags: angular

I want that whenever i click a dropdown in angular that value should passed in object ,that will send that value to api,that is here '28152' will be default everytime but '0002' this should get changed whenever drodpwn value is selected instead of hardcoded value want to change it dynamically at clicking of drpdown

```
 //creating object
postobj = new Post('28152','0002');

//passing value to method which will send the value to service
save(): void {
  this._dataService.PostValues(this.postobj);
  console.log("posted", this.postobj);
}

//service which is sending value to api
PostValues(opost:Post):Observable<Post>{
  console.log("sending post  :- "+ opost.mcn + " : "+ opost.Store_no);
  var requestBody = JSON.stringify(opost);
  return this._http.post<Post>("http://localhost:8080/getTotalSubset",requestBody);

}
```

Comment: can you please your html file

Comment: <div class="drop" style="FLOAT: RIGHT;
    MARGIN-TOP: -1%;">
        <label class="summary" style=" MARGIN-LEFT: -74%;">STORE: </label>
        <select [(ngModel)]="selected" (ngModelChange)='onValueSelected($event)' class="select" style="WIDTH: 122%;
        PADDING: 4%;
        MARGIN-TOP: -31%;">
        <option value="0">--All--</option>
            <option *ngFor="let data of DataConnect" value={{data}}>
             {{data}}
            </option>
        </select>
        <br>
        Value selected is :{{modifieldValue}}
    </div>
  </div> //for drodpwn

Comment: @ram12392 please find html file